# Find specific text in range and change font color

Tags: excel, vba, text, colors, fonts

I'm hoping someone can help me with VBA code to search for specific text in a cell range and change the font color to red.
For example, I'm looking for the word "cat" but I don't want any other words containing the same letters to change, like "concatenate" or "category" or even "cats".

I've used the following, but it is also picking up other words containing the same letters

```vb
Public Sub ChangefontColor()
  Set TextRange = Range("K2:K4584")

  partOfText = "CAT"
  fontColor = 3

  For Each part In TextRange
    lenOfPart = Len(part)
    lenPartOfText = Len(partOfText)

    For i = 1 To lenOfPart
      tempStr = Mid(part, i, lenPartOfText)

      If tempStr = partOfText Then
        part.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lenPartOfText).Font.ColorIndex = fontColor
      End If
    Next i
  Next part
End Sub
```

Comment: Please learn to properly indent your code. It not only makes it easier to read, it makes it easier to trace the flow of execution. Saving a keystroke or two isn't worth the extra effort it makes to read (and in the future, maintain) your code.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

- `preStr / postStr` is a char `before / after` matching part (3 chars).
- **Note:** Your code is a case sensitive comparation. It doesn't matchs `Cat` or `cat`.
- **Bug:** Below code highlighs keyword in `CAT3`. Using `RegExp` is a more reliable option.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ChangefontColor()
    Dim TextRange As Range, lenPartOfText As Long, lenOfPart As Long
    Dim tempStr As String, partOfText As String
    Dim postStr As String, preStr As String, part, i As Long
    Const FONT_COLOR = 3
    Set TextRange = Range("K2:K4584")
    TextRange.Font.Color = vbBlack
    partOfText = "CAT"
    lenPartOfText = Len(partOfText)
    For Each part In TextRange
        lenOfPart = Len(part)
        For i = 1 To lenOfPart - lenPartOfText + 1
            tempStr = Mid(part, i, lenPartOfText)
            If i < lenOfPart - lenPartOfText + 1 Then
                postStr = LCase(Mid(part, i + lenPartOfText, 1))
            Else
                postStr = ""
            End If
            If i = 1 Then
                preStr = ""
            Else
                preStr = LCase(Mid(part, i - 1, 1))
            End If
            If tempStr = partOfText Then
                If (Len(postStr) = 0 Or postStr < "a" Or postStr > "z") And _
                    (Len(preStr) = 0 Or preStr < "a" Or preStr > "z") Then
                    part.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lenPartOfText).Font.ColorIndex = FONT_COLOR
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Option 2:

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim j As Long, c As Range, textRange As Range
    Dim strTxt As String, strMatch As String, strNewTxt As String
    Dim objRegExp As Object, objMatch As Object
    Const FONT_COLOR = 3
    Const KEYWORD = "CAT"
    Set textRange = Range("K2:K4584")
    textRange.Font.Color = vbBlack
    ' Match and submatches
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegExp
        .Pattern = "\b" & KEYWORD & "\b"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        For Each c In textRange
            strTxt = c.Value
            If .Test(strTxt) Then
                Set objMatch = .Execute(strTxt)
                For j = 0 To objMatch.Count - 1
'                    Debug.Print objMatch(j).firstIndex, strTxt
                    c.Characters(Start:=objMatch(j).firstIndex + 1, _
                    Length:=objMatch(j).Length).Font.ColorIndex = FONT_COLOR
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate whether the data contained in the cell is the same as what you are looking for, ignoring even phrases like 'good cat' when searching for 'cat' this code will be useful.

```
Public Sub ChangefontColor(textFind As String, rngTab As Range)
    Dim rngSelect As Range
    
    rngTab.Font.Color = rgbBlack
    
    For Each rngSelect In rngTab
        On Error GoTo jump
            rngSelect.Find(what:=textFind, lookAt:=xlWhole).Font.Color = rgbRed
jump:
        On Error GoTo -1
    Next rngSelect
End Sub
```

call the ChangefontColor sub in another sub or function and replace 'textFind' with the desired text and 'rngTab' with the range of cells to be traversed in the for ...each
that way:

**ChangefontColor textFind, rngTab**